# Problem with CoverageHeatmap (Bioconductor) function in R

Tags: r, heatmap, bioinformatics, bioconductor, genomicranges

I have 2 sets of pairwise alignments, where query genome 1 (q1) is aligned to the reference genome and query genome 2 (q2) is aligned to the same reference genome. Therefore, I have both alignments with a coordinate system in the reference genome. The alignments are in the form of GRanges objects.

I would like to project the breakpoints of q2 onto q1, by aligning the breakpoints of q1 in the center, and look for any clustering of q2 breakpoints around the q1 breakpoints, all in the reference genome coordinate system.

Therefore, I make a GRanges object of q1 with its breakpoints in the center. For example, if there is a breakpoint in q1 relative to the reference genome at scaffold 1, bp 833, then taking a window on 500 either side of this, the q1 GRanges object will have an element:

```
GRanges object with 1 range and 0 metadata columns:
      seqnames    ranges strand
         <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle>
  [1]       S1  333-1333      *
  -------
  seqinfo: 576 sequences from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
```

I then construct a GRanges object of the breakpoints on q2, but all seqlengths are of length 1. I intersect this with the q1 GRanges object, so that q2 only obtains points that can be projected onto q1.

The CoverageHeatmap function requires:

**windows:**
A set of GRanges of equal length

**track:**
A GRanges or RleList object specifying coverage

When I call the CoverageHeatmap function, I always get this error and warning message:

```
Error: subscript contains out-of-bounds ranges
In addition: Warning message:
In e1 == Rle(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
Called from: S4Vectors:::.subscript_error("subscript contains out-of-bounds ", 
    "ranges")
```

I've tried a bunch of things to try and make this work and still get the same error and warning message. This is my code (including when I've tried the function with q2 as a GRanges object and an RleList)

```
## BP Pairwise comparison, using 3rd genome as co-ordinate reference
# q1 is used as the centre point reference, with q2 bps projected on to it. 
# gr_ref_q1 is the pw alignment between the reference and query genome 1
# gr_ref_q2 is the pw alignment between the reference and query genome 2
# We construct two GRanges objects to feed into CoverageHeatMaps
library(schoolmath)
library(heatmaps)
library(IRanges)

bp_3gen_v2 <- function(gr_ref_q1, gr_ref_q2, win){

  # Failsafes (check ref genome is the same, etc)
  if(!(is.even(win))){stop("win should be an even number")}

  ## Construct g1_rco (1st GRanges object)
  # IRanges object
  q1_starts1 <- start(ranges(gr_ref_q1)) - (win*0.5)
  q1_starts2 <- end(ranges(gr_ref_q1)) - (win*0.5)
  q1_starts <- c(q1_starts1, q1_starts2)
  q1_ends1 <- start(ranges(gr_ref_q1)) + (win*0.5)
  q1_ends2 <- end(ranges(gr_ref_q1)) + (win*0.5)
  q1_ends <- c(q1_ends1, q1_ends2)
  q1_ir_ob <- IRanges(start = q1_starts, end = q1_ends) 

  # GR object
  g1_vec_seq <- as.vector(seqnames(gr_ref_q1))
  gr1_seqnames <- c(g1_vec_seq, g1_vec_seq)
  g1_rco <- GRanges(seqnames = gr1_seqnames, ranges = q1_ir_ob, 
                    seqinfo = seqinfo(gr_ref_q1))

  # Remove negative ranges from GR object
  g1_rco <- g1_rco[!(start(ranges(g1_rco)) < 0)] 



  ## Construct g2_rco (2nd GRanges object)
  # IRanges object
  q2_starts <- start(ranges(gr_ref_q2))
  q2_ends <- end(ranges(gr_ref_q2))
  q2_bps <- c(q2_starts, q2_ends)
  q2_ir_ob <- IRanges(start = q2_bps, end = q2_bps)
  # GR object
  g2_vec_seq <- as.vector(seqnames(gr_ref_q2))
  gr2_seqnames <- c(g2_vec_seq, g2_vec_seq)
  g2_rco <- GRanges(seqnames = gr2_seqnames, ranges = q2_ir_ob,
                    seqinfo = seqinfo(gr_ref_q2))

  # Try removing anywhere in g2_rco that is not present in g1_rco
  # find intersection of seqnames 
  g_inter <- intersect(g1_vec_seq, g2_vec_seq)
  # apply to g2_rco to remove out of bound scaffols
  g2_rco <- g2_rco[seqnames(g2_rco) == g_inter]
  # now to remove out of bound ranges (GRanges object)
  g2_red <- intersect(g1_rco, g2_rco)
  # And try as RleList object
  g2_red_rle <- coverage(g2_red)


  # Heatmap
  heat_map <- CoverageHeatmap(windows = g1_rco, track = g2_red_rle)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid these problems and to achieve what you need, the simplest solution is to have the same seqlevels and seqlenghts for both GRanges. If you know this for your reference then provide it, if not try this:

First example datasets:

```
library(heatmaps)
gr1 = GRanges(seqnames=c(1,2,3),
IRanges(start=c(1,101,1001),end=c(500,600,1500)))

gr2 = GRanges(seqnames=c(2,2,3,3),
IRanges(start=c(1,301,1,1201),end=c(2500,4800,3500,9700)))
```

Then we make a combined range to get the levels and lengths:

```
combined= range(c(gr1,gr2))

seqlevels(gr1) = as.character(seqnames(combined))
seqlevels(gr2) = as.character(seqnames(combined))
seqlengths(gr1) = end(combined)
seqlengths(gr2) = end(combined)
```

Then the heatmap can be easily obtained by:

```
CoverageHeatmap(gr1,coverage(gr2))
```

Or if you only want to look at gr1 windows that have some values in gr2, then do:

```
CoverageHeatmap(gr1[countOverlaps(gr1,gr2)>0],coverage(gr2))
```

Comment: I do have seqlevels and seqlengths for the ref genome, but it just seems to cause more errors.

I started to play around with the set up you suggested above. Your example works just fine, but I have entered numbers that cause the out-of-bound range error to occur, but I don't understand the pattern of what causes this. For example, this setup works just fine:


But this set up causes the error: GRanges object contains 1 out-of-bound range located on sequence 3.

Comment: yes... but you don't need to convert back and forth just to obtain the windows. stick with granges and everything should be ok

Comment: And I can't do anything else by just reading your code. You need to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Playing around with the setup you suggested, I have these values that work:

`
gr1 = GRanges(seqnames = c(1,2,3), IRanges(start = c(1,101,101), end = c(200,300, 300)))

gr2 = GRanges(seqnames = c(1,2,3), IRanges(start = c(1,1,1), end = c(50,50,50) ))
`

And these that don't:

`
gr1 = GRanges(seqnames = c(1,2,3), IRanges(start = c(1,101,201), end = c(200,300, 400)))

gr2 = GRanges(seqnames = c(1,2,3), IRanges(start = c(1,1,101), end = c(50,50,150) ))
`
When all I've done is shift the sequence 3 values. Could you explain why it stops working?

Comment: @CharlieW, Thanks for pointing it out.. Yes I made a mistake, it should be end of ranges, instead of width. See updated code above

Comment: So if you have seqlevels and seqlengths, then always work with GRanges because you will inherit seqlengths and seqlevel. anything that is done is IRanges can be done in GRanges.

Comment: Yes that's working now, thank you for your help. I will try implementing it into my larger code